# How do I get a direct url to the videos hosted on this site?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, html-agility-pack

I would like to scrap the video url from [this](http://mp4engine.com/embed-ady6poozql26-722x420.html) website. Unfortunately, the code of the player is `p,a,c,k,e,d`, so I can't extract the `file_url` property directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a browser plugin like [video downloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/)

Comment: I'm not trying to download the video. I need to get the link using C#, programatically....